# Aws sqs integration access violation

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to integrate aws simple queue service (sqs) in the Unreal Engine project. I've built the whole aws c++ sdk from the github source following documentation. My build parameters are below:

```
 cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DUSE_WINDOWS_DLL_SEMATICS=ON -DUSE_IMPORT_EXPORT=ON
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" INSTALL.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Linked all necessary dlls to the UE project:

```
// These macros are necessary for the aws
Definitions.Add("USE_IMPORT_EXPORT");
Definitions.Add("USE_WINDOWS_DLL_SEMANTICS");

PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(libDirectory, "aws", "aws-cpp-sdk-core.lib"));
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(libDirectory, "aws", "aws-c-event-stream.lib"));
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(libDirectory, "aws", "aws-checksums.lib"));
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(libDirectory, "aws", "aws-c-common.lib"));
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(libDirectory, "aws", "aws-cpp-sdk-sqs.lib"));
```

The problem is when I try to run simple code for receiving messages copied from aws c++ example page it falls down with access violation. As you can see on the pictures below, there is some mess in the ClientConfiguration object.

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22j6.png)
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LBrf.png)

When I run this same code with same dlls in the new VS c++ plain project without Unreal Engine it runs fine. I tried many things like building aws sdk c++ as static libraries. It crashes also somewhere else when freeing some memory inside aws library.

I don't know where is the problem? It looks like some problem with memory management.

The whole testing UE project with aws libs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U1Pknx6Mx48NN9ULk_09aSysxM0FFjbg/view?usp=sharing

I would be very grateful for any help.

Regards.

Petr

Comment: I've found the solution finally. The only way to get it working was to build aws libraries with Microsoft Vcpkg. There has to be some additional settings when building. Dlls created by building from source or Nuget packages did not work with UE4.

Comment: What additional settings did you use when building? I'm having this exact same issue right now.

Comment: Just build it with Vcpkg Microsoft tool and it should work because their ecosystem sets all necessary. By "additional settings when building" I meant building from source on your own (without vcpkg) like I did firstly.